# How to Invert an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

To invert an array in Javascript

I have an array like

```
[S, L, 20, 30]
```

But I need to display an array like

```
[S, 20 , L, 30]
```

Comment: do you have a unidimensional or bidimensional array? give code!

Comment: array is in  unidimensional

Comment: What exactly is the sorting pattern?

Comment: my array comes like this pattern  S L M 20 30 60 and i need S 20 L 30 M 60.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have string and number in pairs. You can try following logic

```
var abc = ['S', 'L', 'M', 20, 30, 60];

var updated = [];
var mid = abc.length/2;

for (var i=0; i< mid;i++) {
   updated.push(abc[i]);
   updated.push(abc[mid+i]);
}

console.log(updated);
```